# How to start activity from viewmodel on login success in mvvm pattern

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-viewmodel

Hi I have one activity `LoginActivity.kt` and `LoginViewModel`. I am calling the login API in the `login` method of `LoginViewModel`. On success of it, I want to start home activity. What is the correct way to do it in MVVM approach ?

LoginViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel<LoginNavigator>(), AnkoLogger {

    val emailField = ObservableField<String>()

    private val email: String
        get() = emailField.get()

    val passwordField = ObservableField<String>()

    private val password: String
        get() = passwordField.get()

    val progressVisibility: ObservableInt = ObservableInt(View.GONE)

    @Suppress("PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE")
    fun login(view: View) {
      // here I am calling API and on success
    }

    /**
     * Validate email and password. It checks email and password is empty or not
     * and validate email address is correct or not
     * @param email email address for login
     * @param password password for login
     * @return true if email and password pass all conditions else false
     */
    private fun isEmailAndPasswordValid(email: String, password: String): Boolean {

        if (email.isEmpty()) return false

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) return false

        if (password.isEmpty()) return false

        return true
    }

}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity(), LoginNavigator {

    @Inject
    lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        performDependencyInjection()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val activityLoginBinding: ActivityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityLoginBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_login)
        activityLoginBinding.loginViewModel = loginViewModel
        loginViewModel.mNavigator = this
    }
```

Comment: Why you need to make the viewmodel inside the databinding instance ? It would be a trouble if you have advanced ui flow(such as your question) in your activity since the viewmodel does not contains the object of the binding.

Comment: @LongRanger I dont know much, newbie with mvvm. can you please suggest

Comment: Let say if you login failure in your view model and you need to make a toast or snackbar to tell the user about this information, you will have a trouble to create these views since you dont have the view or context inside the viewmodel. I suggest you to  follow the google sample about aac. You will know more about it. It provides the simple sample to guide you how to solve these problems in a easy way.

Comment: @LongRanger can you suggest specific file of that sample where context or view is being used in viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say a simple scenario using your login idea, user login fail and the app need to make a simple Toast or SnackBar to show the related information such as "Your username and password is incorrect". The code you need is

Toast (Required `Context`)

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

Snackbar (Required `View`)

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout),
                                R.string.email_archived, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

If you want to use it inside your ViewModel (I am not familiar with Kotlin)

```
  @Suppress("PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE")
    void function login(final View view) {
      // here I am calling API and on success
      repo.login(result -> {
           if(result.statusCode == 401)
           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Login failed...", duration).show();
      });
    }
```

You are going to find the reference of the activity in the reverse way, which make more complex code and hard to maintain since every time you need to get the reference of **the activity or context to do something related to the view or activity in the view model instead of the Activity**

From the [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/search/SearchFragment.java), you can see `doSearch()` function is called when the input is done. And after the search result fetched , the binding will put the latest result back to this observer , and now it is the activity job to update the result in the adapter.

```
private void initSearchInputListener() {
        binding.get().input.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                doSearch(v);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        binding.get().input.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                doSearch(v);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    private void doSearch(View v) {
        String query = binding.get().input.getText().toString();
        // Dismiss keyboard
        dismissKeyboard(v.getWindowToken());
        binding.get().setQuery(query);
        searchViewModel.setQuery(query);
    }

private void initRecyclerView() {

        binding.get().repoList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)
                        recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                int lastPosition = layoutManager
                        .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastPosition == adapter.get().getItemCount() - 1) {
                    searchViewModel.loadNextPage();
                }
            }
        });
        searchViewModel.getResults().observe(this, result -> {
            binding.get().setSearchResource(result);
            binding.get().setResultCount((result == null || result.data == null)
                    ? 0 : result.data.size());
            adapter.get().replace(result == null ? null : result.data);
            binding.get().executePendingBindings();
        });

        searchViewModel.getLoadMoreStatus().observe(this, loadingMore -> {
            if (loadingMore == null) {
                binding.get().setLoadingMore(false);
            } else {
                binding.get().setLoadingMore(loadingMore.isRunning());
                String error = loadingMore.getErrorMessageIfNotHandled();
                if (error != null) {
                    Snackbar.make(binding.get().loadMoreBar, error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            binding.get().executePendingBindings();
        });
    }
```

Also, according to the answer from @Emanuel S, you will see his argument

> WeakReference to a NavigationController which holds the Context of the
>   Activity. This is a common used pattern for handling context-bound
>   stuff inside a ViewModel.
>
> I highly decline this for several reasons. First: that usually means
>   that you have to keep a reference to your NavigationController which
>   fixes the context leak, but doesnt solve the architecture at all.
>
> The best way (in my oppinion) is using LiveData which is lifecycle
>   aware and can do all the wanted stuff.

Another question you may think about it if you implement ui action inside the viewmodel  , if you get a NullPointerException in your view or context or do some enhancement about it, which class you will find first ? ViewModel or Activity ? Since the first one you hold the UI action , the second one you hold the data binding. Both may be possible in the troubleshoot.